# How to design a dynamic type system without the RTTI?

Tags: c++, types, casting, rtti

I know this question is somewhat broad and imprecise, but this is what I want:

```
struct DynTyped { /* HOW? */ };
class Animal : public DynTyped {};
class Dog : public Animal {};
class Cat : public Animal {};

// expect to work
Animal* a1 = new Dog;
Dog* d1 = DOWNCAST<Dog*>(a1);
d1->hello();

// expect to throw
Animal* a2 = new Cat;
Dog* d2 = DOWNCAST<Dog*>(a2);
d2->hello();
```

One way I can do it is to set a field in base class.

```
class Animal {
enum AnimalType { Dog, Cat };
protected:
AnimalType type_;
}
```

But I want a way to implement it in a higher base class, for I may have a shape base class and I don't want to do that type field trick again.

Comment: With RTTI: `DOWNCAST` is just `dynamic_cast` and returns `nullptr` in your second exemple => UB

Comment: Without RTTI: `DOWNCAST` is still `dynamic_cast` but this time returns `a2` cast => UB

Comment: I want to throw without RTTI.

Comment: What is your beef with RTTI? Either use it, or go with alternative designs. You can't emulate it.

Comment: I guess that may need a unique type id field for every class, but I just don't know how to do it.

Comment: To Deidei, my project has disabled the RTTI, but I do need a safe type casting. It does't relate to hierarchy, another case is I just have a untyped pointer and need to cast to a type safely.

Comment: [Here's one way](https://llvm.org/docs/HowToSetUpLLVMStyleRTTI.html). But I do warn you, it requires boiler-plate on your part. Much boiler-plate.

Comment: @StoryTeller that's awful! How is _that_ on the official LLVM doc?

Comment: @YSC - That's just the way it goes. They deemed built-in RTTI as two slow for their needs (ironic since they also emit RTTI support for client code). So a home-brewed solution was created. They gained the performance they wanted out of it, so I suppose it's not just programming to superstition.

Comment: What is your aim, why you want to avoid RTTI? You want it to be more efficient or you want to save memory that RTTI would require?

Comment: @SunYi-Ming: do you need support for multiple inheritance? Cross casting?

Comment: Just because the project need to be very compact to place on android.

Comment: @geza No I don't need the inheritance stuff, I just need to cast a object to duck when it is a duck really.

Comment: @SunYi-Ming: "inheritance stuff"?

Comment: @geza I mean, I don't need inheritance function. I need to check whether an object is of a type exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a perfect replacement, however, CRTP has potential that you want...

BTW, Why do you want to avoid RTTI? There is no way to emulate RTTI.

Comment: My project manager decide to avoid it. It doesn't relate to RTTI, and I don't want a FULL RTTI implementation, I just want to cast to a type safely.

Comment: How CRTP can do it?

Comment: I don't know good English information, however, Japanese information is hre(Please use Google Translate)
https://qiita.com/Riyaaaa_a/items/a9af401520f238f45b80

Comment: I read the article, but I still don't know how to do it, and I think my question relate dynamic field value.

Comment: dynamic field value must resolve on runtime. This means use virtual or reproduce vtable with dirty buggy implementaion.
To use CRTP, change logic to static.

As a result, A most simple, easy, non-buggy, firstest way is use virtual and RTTI.

Answer (score 0):

This might seem trivial but you can do:

```
class Dog;
class Cat;
struct DynTyped { virtual Dog*AsDog() {return 0;} virtual Cat*AsCat() {return 0;};
class Animal : public DynTyped {};
class Dog : public Animal {virtual Dog*AsDog() {return this;};};
class Cat : public Animal {virtual Cat*AsCat() {return this;};}
```

Comment: nice trick, but mine is better IMHO :). You'll need to know all the beasts in the base class, you also inflate the size of `vtable`. Speaking theoretically you'll need O(N^2) memory to support N classes.

Comment: It depends. If you have "class GrandRetriever:public Dog" you can  add "AsGrandRetriever()" in the solution I presented; and keep "AsDog". Your solution doesn't naturally handle that case.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add a virtual function to your base class, which will identify the actual type of your object at run-time. Then you can create a template wrapper function that would encapsulate the actual type casting.

I mean this:

```
class Animal {
public:
    virtual int get_Type() const = 0;
};
class Dog : public Animal {
public:
    static const int s_Type = 1;
    virtual int get_Type() const { return s_Type; }
};
class Cat : public Animal {
public:
    static const int s_Type = 2;
    virtual int get_Type() const { return s_Type; }
};

template <class T>
T* DynamicCast(Animal* p)
{
    return (T::s_Type == p->get_Type()) ? static_cast<T*>(p) : NULL;
}
```

This is the idea. You can use any type to you prefer to discover the actual object type, in this example I used `int`, you may create an `enum` for this.

Note also that this works in case the types match, in contrast RTTI works also if the target type is inherited, i.e. source object may be of a derived type.
This is so because the RTTI info is more complex, it contains the whole hierarchy.

Comment: @PasserBy: yes.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid virtual method?

Comment: @SunYi-Ming: you **must** have some type information in your object, this is unavoidable. You may add a member to your base class that identifies the type, but this is inferior solution because this member is per-object. OTOH adding a virtual function is per-class.

Comment: @valdo There is no difference. In the virtual function case each object will have a hidden member variable containing the vtable-pointer.

Comment: @Johan: this is true when you add the 1st virtual function. But if your object already have them - then nothing is added to the obj.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use virtual functions for casting. You can do something like this:

```
#include <exception>

class Animal;
class Dog;
class Cat;

struct InvalidConversion : public std::exception
{
};

struct DynTyped { 
  virtual Animal *IsAnimal() { throw InvalidConversion(); }
  virtual Dog *IsDog() { throw InvalidConversion(); }
  virtual Cat *IsCat() { throw InvalidConversion(); }
};

class Animal : public DynTyped 
{
  virtual Animal *IsAnimal() override { return this; }
};

class Dog : public Animal
{
  virtual Dog *IsDog() override { return this; }
};

class Cat : public Animal
{
  virtual Cat *IsCat() override { return this; }
};
```

And then use it:

```
// expect to work
Animal* a1 = new Dog;
Dog* d1 = a1->IsDog();
d1->hello();

// expect to throw
Animal* a2 = new Cat;
Dog* d2 = a2->IsDog();
d2->hello();
```